# how to reset a list when a button is pressed

Tags: list, flutter, button

How to reset my list when I press the restart button? When I run the code the question number turns to zero but the question is not updated.

```
addQuestion(BuildContext context) {
if (questionNumber < _questionBank.length - 1) {
  questionNumber++;
  print(questionNumber);
  print(_questionBank[questionNumber].answer);
} else {
  return Alert(
      context: context,
      title: 'Finished',
      type: AlertType.info,
      buttons: [
        DialogButton(
          onPressed: () {
            questionNumber = 0;
            scoreKeeper.clear();
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('restart'),
        ),
      ]).show();
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `setState` in `DialogButton`'s `onPressed` function.

```
DialogButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      questionNumber = 0;
      scoreKeeper.clear();
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
),
```

Comment: Don't need to put `Navigator.pop(context);` in `setState`.